# In AWS step functions what is 'matches string' in the choice state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, aws-step-functions

In choice state you can set various filters. Among the filters you can set is 'matches string' which is represented like this: '~='.

You can also set is equal to string constant which is represented like this: '=='. This I understand.

What does 'matches string' filter mean in the choice state in step function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for wildcard matching with `*`

e.g. if the filter is `foo*`, it will match `foobar`, `foobaz`, etc.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html):

> String comparison against patterns with one or more wildcards (“*”) can be performed with the StringMatches comparison operator. The wildcard character is escaped by using the standard \\ (Ex: “\\*”). No characters other than “*” have any special meaning during matching.